# .docx and xlsx file not viewing in google docs viewer

Tags: wamp, google-docs-api

Am using Google docs viewer to view documents in my websites. ( https://docs.google.com/viewer )

when I try to view a file using Google docs from my dedicated server domain the file is not viewed correctly only for docx & xlsx

I have listed the scenarios below

https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://----.com/testfinal.docx

Using web server wamp

When I tried to view the same files(docx & xlxs) in other domains,dropbox etc.. its working good.

Can you please help me in figuring out the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wamp server apache httpd.conf file uncomment the mime_module and other file types need to add in the file.

please follow the step in the link below

http://niallodoherty.com/post.cfm/microsoft-office-2007-mime-types-with-apache-and-iis